# Many people squat/sit with their buttocks almost to the ground, whats it called?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests

I notice Japanese people squatting in this position for long periods of time without using a chair/stool. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most fitting verb for this that I can think of is しゃがむ, rarely written with kanji as 蹲む.  Similar terms include かがむ and こごむ; however, these don't have the same sense of "squatting *for long periods of time*", and might better be translated as "to crouch [such as to pick something up, for かがむ; or to hide, for こごむ]".

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Eiríkr Útlendi's answer, I just want to add some slang expressions: うんこ座り{すわり} or ヤンキー座り{すわり}. "Poop squat" and "yankii squat", respectively. The first one is obvious considering the traditional Japanese-style toilets. The second term refers to the stereotypical image of juvenile delinquents/hoodlums in Japan, ヤンキー, who are known to squat like this.

Comment: I don't think "thugs" is a good translation of ヤンキー - (チンピラ may be a closer translation of "thugs"); the stereotypical British [chav and chavette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chav) is closer in image, if not fashion, to how I picture a ヤンキー.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I agree chav and chavette is a better comparison.

Comment: I also know it as うんこずわり with ず.